# BehaviorSubject<Object[]> returns faulty array on first .subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have a BehaviorSubject and the first .subscribe callback returns an Array with 6 Objects and on a console-output, it shows `length: 6` but every for-loop only iterates 5 times and even console.log(arr.length) outputs '5'

I do not really know how to reproduce this, but t have following code:

```
public objects: BehaviorSubject<Object[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

// other class
            this.objectService.objects.subscribe(_objects => {
                if (_objects) {
                    for (const obj of _objects) {
                        console.log(obj);
                    }
                    console.log(_objects);
                    console.log(_objects.length);
                }
            });
```

Output:
[image: Output]

How can this happen? A lot of different services write (objects.next) to this BehaviorSubject, but how can I prevent this from happening?
It only happens the first time 'objects' is .next-ed, from the second .next on this code works perfectly and shows the real length.

I also tested .find and .filter on the array, but it only can filter the 5 last entries and not the first one

Comment: I try to fix this since this morning.
It seems like it always jumps over the first entry of the array.
Only thing I got working now was a complete workaround with different BehaviorSubjects that track the amount of the different types in this array because this `for (const obj of _objects)` never works the first time it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your Behavior subjects should be either protected or private. Otherwise you are opening to vulnerabilities.

With that said. You are creating a behavior subject with initial value of (`[]`). when you subscribe, that value is emitted (`[]`). Then, the first `next()` emits a new value. Since both overlap, then you get a 6-length array. If I'm not wrong, this shouldn't happen if you use a Subject() instead of a BehaviorSubject, or is merely a mistake of console.log outputting too much.

Comment: initially it is [] but it only gets subscribed later, then some code does .next the first time and this always happens => wrong length. Any following .next calls all the results in console.log and UI are correct. I sometimes have this kind of errors and i never was able to solve it. would be rellay helpful top know what in typescript can cause this. Sometimes the https://i.imgur.com/oiA6acN.png output even shows Array(5) at the start and everything same outputs. Its wired

Comment: Thing is console.log sometimes shows values 'evaluated just now.' You should use debugging to sort these types of problems because .log will lie to you. On the other hand, I'm not sure if what I told you helped you, but try changing it to a Subject() because BehaviorSubjects always get a value on subscription (last value). Subjects don't get a value unless you are subscribed when emitted. There's also ReplaySubject, etc. Check it! rxjs is fun (truthfully!)